# How and where do you report a hijackers IP address?

Tags: gmail

Saturday, June 29, 2013 1:23:41 AM UTC 
IP Address: 201.243.155.70 
Location: San Cristobal, Venezuela

This is the suspicious sign in information on my account. I did some research and others have fallen victim to this Taringa hack.

Here is some of the information that I have gathered from this specific attack...

> "Hey man I want to contribute :::: .. Long live the ethical hacking, I
>   leave lammer data: IP Location: Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic Of
>   CANTV Servicios Venezuela Caracas Resolve Host:
>   190-204-152-8.dyn.dsl.cantv.net IP Address: inetnum: 190.200/13
>   status: Allocated owner: CANTV Servicios, Venezuela ownerid:
>   VE-CSVE-LACNIC responsible: Ramón Cabello address: Second Avenue Palos
>   Grandes, 000, Entre Av Fr address: 1060 - Caracas - MI country: VE
>   phone: +58 212 2095710 [] nic-hdl: LUM person: Ramón Cabello e-mail:
>   address: Second Avenue Palos Grandes, Entre Av Fr, 000, address: 1060
>   - Caracas - MI country: VE phone: +58 212 2095609 [] And I think the Fake calls himself "Azafram" ............ K is helpful and trainga
>   .... take legal action ...... ATTE N3w_R4c3"

So, back to my main question... Where and how does one report this information or is it already logged?

Answer (score 1):

Suspicious activity isn't logged - and I don't think you can report it - because it's your account that's being misused. You should change your password immediately, and opt-in for two-factor authentication